# How to trace class field accesses of certain classes only in Scala?

Tags: scala, trace

I would like to use variable tracer for Scala programs which traces reads and writes of certain class fields.

For example, if I have a custom actor class like:

```
class Server extends Actor {
  var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case A                   => counter += 1
    case B if (counter == 0) => ...
    case B =>                   ...
  }
}
```

The class uses Akka's actor type.
I want to trace all fields of classes which inherit from `Actor` such as `counter` and distinguish between reads and writes. Note that I do not want to trace other class fields!

Is there any tracer framework for Scala which allows tracing reads/writes of class fields for certain classes only?
If there is no other way, I am also willing to instrument the Scala code, changing all fields to a custom type with operators. In this case I would need some instrumentation framework for Scala code.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked here: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-instrument-source-code-of-existing-scala-libraries/4717

They recommended something like https://scalameta.org/